# Simple image generator using html input and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out and construct a code using javascript x html fields, to define a specific number that will be used to start and control a loop and will result on displaying images.

Assume that [enclose] are fields and will be entered by the user;

Starting Number: [userinputStart] 
Ending Number: [useerinputEnd]

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x="", i = [userinputStart];
do
  {
  x=x + "<img src=\"http://examplepage.com/" + i + ".jpg\">";
  i++;
  }
while (i< [userinputEnd])  
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Generate</button>

<div id="display"></div>
```

If User inputs: [userinputStart] = 4, [userinputEnd] = 6

The display should be images with src=

```
examplepage.com/4.jpg
examplepage.com/5.jpg
examplepage.com/6.jpg
```

I can do the same function using java6 but I'm not really sure how to- in html with fields.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't taken the input from anywhere. The best way to get the input from the user is to use a `prompt()` or an `input` field. In your case, it is easier to use the `prompt()` for getting the inputs from the user.

Change your code to:

```
i = prompt("Enter the starting value:", "here...");
```

And in your `while` loop, do not get the input from the user there. Instead store it in a variable like:

```
j = prompt("Enter the ending value:", "here...");
```

And make your `while` loop look like:

```
while (i < j)
```

But the best way to do it is, you need to pass the parameters to the `myFunction` itself, something like:

```
myFunction(i, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to modify your **function** to be able to receive params as follows:

```
function myFunction(userinputStart, userinputEnd){

// your stuff

}
```

And then add a **HTML button** in your code to call your function, using the textfields values as params as follows:

```
<input type=button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('txt1').value,document.getElementById('txt2').value)" />
```

All that supossing that your function body is correct to achieve your goal